# Shiny introduces strange character during download

Tags: csv, unicode, download, shiny, special-characters

I have tried to create Shiny [application](https://shansh.shinyapps.io/post_hoc_table/), which supposed to produce ANOVA *post-hoc* table with mean values followed by standard deviations and separated by plus-minus sign (±). Everything works nice in RStudio environment and when aplication is reproduced in local web-server (both, render and download). Even when I try to run application on Shiny server it renders correct table to HTML, but when I try to download table as .csv downloadHandler introduces a strange character (Â) in front of plus-minus sign. How can I override this strange sign introduction? I have tried to enforce "UTF-8" encoding in many different places in code, but with no success. Moreover, I have tries everything what is specified in [Unicode characters in Shiny apps](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/unicode.html), but again with no success. The complete code is included within the application (showcase). Sample table for running application could be found [here](https://github.com/Shansh/post_hoc/blob/master/sample_table.csv), and downloaded table with introduced Â's could be found [here](https://github.com/Shansh/post_hoc/blob/master/post_hoc_table.csv) (special character Â is not visible at GitHub view for some reason, but when you download it it becames visible).

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461907/html-encoding-issues-%C3%82-character-showing-up-instead-of-nbsp)?  It's not about shiny, but it does discuss the spontaneous appearance of A-circumflex characters immediately before unusual characters.

Comment: Also, [this site](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) specifically mentions the issue of `±` turning into `Â±`.

Comment: Thank you @Paul for your suggestions. There are plenty of explanations about utf-8 encoding issues, but unfortunately I couldn't find right answer there. But you encouraged me to search more deeply. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34936168/r-shiny-download-data-encoding-issue), I have found what I was looking for. Now, when I have put encoding parameter in import file line `read.csv(infile$datapath, header = TRUE, encoding = "UTF-8")` and encoding for exporting file line `write.csv(tableInput(), file, row.names=FALSE, fileEncoding = "latin1")`, everything works just nice.